# Cookie script not working

Tags: javascript, cookies

i  have cookie code which is not working dont know whats the problem.This code is working in another script but not in it.

CODE:

```
function get_cookie(Name) {
    var search = Name + "=";
    if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
        offset = document.cookie.indexOf(search)

        // cookie exist, update expiry date of the same cookie
        if (offset != -1) {
            cookie_info = document.cookie.split('=');
            cookie_info = cookie_info[0]+"=" + cookie_info[1];

            // add 30 days expiry
            var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime()+(30*24*60*60*1000));
            var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();

            cookie_info += expires + ";path=/";

            document.cookie = cookie_info;
       }
   }}

function loadCokie() {
    if (get_cookie('popup')=='') {
        alert("hello");
        document.cookie="popup=yes"
    }
}
```

THnx in advance

Comment: What is not working? Do you get an error while trying this?

Comment: A few problems with your code. First, `if (offset != -1)` should be `if (offset !== -1)`. Second, you're not accounting for multiple cookies. if there is more than one cookie, then your `document.cookie` will look something like `popup=bob; cookie2=bill;`, so you would need to check for existance of `; ` and split there first, then get the one with the name you want and then split that at the `=`

Comment: no error is shown in the console but alert doesn't open's

Comment: @SpYk3HH i changed `if (offset != -1)` to  `(offset !== -1)` but nothing happens

Comment: as i mentioned that was only one small problem. The next part is dealing with the string. Go to the first line inside that if statement (cause it will pass) and add the line `console.log(document.cookie);` and then check your console and see what string appears. that's the kind of string you need to break down, but if all you see is one cookie, then you need save that string somewhere, add another cookie, and look again and see the diffence I was referring to before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a suggestion, but you could just do:

```
if ( ! localStorage.getItem('visited')) {
    localStorage.setItem('visited', true);
    alert('Hello, new visitor !');
}
```

and if you have to support older browsers, you'd add the polyfill from **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Storage)** that falls back to cookies automagically.

**EDIT:**

As for your original code, you never execute any of the functions, and if a cookie doesn't exist, it wont return an empty string, so the logic is flawed, I changed it a little :

```
function get_cookie(c_name) {
  var c_value = document.cookie;
  var c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + c_name + "=");
  if (c_start == -1) {
    c_start = c_value.indexOf(c_name + "=");
  }
  if (c_start == -1) {
    c_value = null;
  }else{
    c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;
    var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);
    if (c_end == -1) {
      c_end = c_value.length;
    }
    c_value = unescape(c_value.substring(c_start,c_end));
  }
  return c_value;
}

function set_cookie(c_name,value,exdays) {
  var exdate=new Date();
  exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
  var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
  document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function loadCokie() {
  if ( ! get_cookie('popup')) {
    alert("hello");
    set_cookie('popup', 'yes', 30);
  }
}

loadCokie();
```

Comment: thnxx ..its working and how can i open popup at the time of exit.using `onUnload` is ok?

Comment: hello..how can i open popup on window close i tried but nothing works 
  `window.onbeforeunload = function () {
            loadSound();
        };`

Comment: You can't, all you can do is open the standard confirm box with a custom message, anything else wont work as it would be annoying you could stop the browser from redirecting while showing ads or other custom popup stuff.